# Prove that every closed ball in $\Bbb R^n$ is sequentially compact.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, general-topology, sequences-and-series

**Question:**

Prove that every closed ball in $\Bbb R^n$ is sequentially compact.

---

A subset $E$ of $\Bbb R^n$ is said to be squentially compact $\iff$ every sequence $x_k\in E$ has convergent subsequence whose limit belongs to $E$

---

**Solution:**

Let $B_R(a)$ be closed ball. Let $x_k$ be a sequence in $B_R(a)$

Then, $$\vert\vert x_k-a\vert\vert \le M$$ for $M>0$

By the triangle inequality,

$$\vert\vert x_k-a\vert\vert \le \vert \vert x_k\vert \vert +\vert\vert a\vert \le M \ \  \Rightarrow \vert\vert x_k\vert\vert \le \vert\vert a\vert\vert +M $$

So the sequence $x_k$ is bounded.

By Bolzano W. Theorem, $x_k$ has convergent subsequences.

---

Now I need to show that these convergent subsequences have a limit point in $B_R(a)$.

But how? Please explain this part. Thank you:)

Comment: you haven't yet exploited  the closedness of the ball

Comment: Do I need to explain the closedness of ball? @Quickbeam2k1

Comment: you know that every $x_k$ is in $B_R(a)$ and a subsequence converges to some $x_0$. Can $x_0$ be outside of $B_R(a)$?

Comment: @Bstr "exploit", not "explain".

Comment: @DanielFischer that's its mean is "take advantage of, make use of..etc". Is it? Sorry, I am not native spoken in English.

Comment: No, $x_0$ must be in B_R(a)$. I guess this is a rule for convergence. @Quickbeam2k1

Comment: This is rather a possible definition of closedness. I'm also not a native speaker. So sorry for the inconvenience :)

Comment: Yes, or simply "use". You have a sequence in a closet set, so its limit can't lie outside.

Comment: Okay, I understand. Thank you :) by the way, No problem:) @Quickbeam2k1

Comment: Okay, thank you for the explanation:) @DanielFischer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you wrote is not entirely correct. What you should've used is the reverse triangle inequality $$|\lVert x_k\rVert-\lVert a\rVert |\leq \lVert x_k-a\rVert\leq M$$

This gives that $$-M\leq\lVert x_k\rVert-\lVert a\rVert\leq M$$ $$\lVert a\rVert-M\leq\lVert x_k\rVert\leq M+\lVert a\rVert$$

so the sequence is bounded. It seems strange to use Bolzano Weiertrass, since what you're being asked to prove is precisely that theorem. I would argue as follows. You probably know the result of Bolzano Weiertrass for $\Bbb R^1$. But one can extend it easily to $\Bbb R^n$. Consider a bounded sequence in $\Bbb R^n$ $${\bf x}_k=(x_{k,1},x_{k,2},\ldots,x_{k,n})$$

By Bolzano Weiertrass, $x_{k,1}$ has convergent subsequence, $y_{k,1}=x_{n_k,1}$. Now look at $${\bf x}_{n_k}={\bf y}_k=(y_{k,1},y_{k,2},\ldots,y_{k,n})$$

This is now a subsequence of the whole ${\bf x}_k$. We know the *subsequence* $y_{k,2}=x_{n_k,2}$ is bounded, so it has a convergent subsequence by Bolzano Weiertrass in $\Bbb R^1$, which we will call $z_{k,2}=y_{k_j,2}$. Now we have a subsequence of ${\bf y}_k$ (which was already a subsequence of ${\bf x}$, whose two first coordinates have matching subindices and both converge. And as you should see by now, we ultimately obtain a subsequence of "deepness $n$" (meaning it will be the subsequence of a subsequence of ... a subsequence of ${\bf x}$ - $n$ times) which we can call $${\bf x'}_j=(x_{j,1}^\prime,\ldots, x_{j,n}^\prime)$$ which converges, since each coordinate converges. Thus, Bolzano Weiertrass is proven for $\Bbb R^n$. Since closed balls are closed sets, your claim follows, since closed sets contain their limit points.

> **NOTE** Bolzano Weiertrass is precisely the statement that every closed ball in $\Bbb R^n$ is compact, equivalently sequentially compact, or that $\Bbb R^n$ is locally compact, that is, every point $a\in\Bbb R^n$ has a neighborhood whose closure is compact.

Comment: I understand well. Do I need to show that closed balls are closed set?

Comment: @Bstr That is not too complicated to do. It suffices you show that if ${\bf x}_k \to \bf b$ and $\lVert {\bf x}-{\bf a}\rVert\leq r$ then $\lVert {\bf b}-{\bf a}\rVert \leq r$. Try doing it with a few examples $n=1,2,3$ and then try to see if you can generalize it to any $n$.

Answer (score 2):

First, note that a closed ball is a closed set.

To prove this, let $E\subset \mathbb{R}$ is a closed ball of radius $R$ around $y$. Let $x\in E^{C}$. Now, let $r=d(x,y)-R>0$ and $z\in B_{r}(x)$. Then $$d(y,x)\le d(y,z)+d(z,x)<d(y,z)+r\\
\Rightarrow d(y,z)>R$$ Hence $z\notin E$ and hence the open ball $B_r(x)$ is totally contained in $E^{C}$. hence $E^{C}$ is open and hence $E$ is closed.

Now, since you've got a convergent (sub)sequence in a closed set, it is going to converge to some point in the set itself, by definition of closed set. So you're done.

Comment: It is possible, that part of the question is to show that a closed ball is a closed set.

Comment: yes, that is a nice exercise also.